# When to update information for ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

If I ave an `activity` with a `viewPAger` on it and two sets of data that I want to display, is it best to have one `fragment` and load information into `textViews` based on position passed from `activity` or better to create more than one fragment and load the one needed?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class testFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PAGE = "pageNumber";
    private static final int DEFAULT_INT = 0;

    TextView header, sd1;
    int h1, page = 0;

    public testFragment (){
    }

    public testFragment newInstance(int pageNumber) {
        testFragment fragment = new testFragment ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            page = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_high_scores_page, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        header = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.modes_header);
        sd1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stat_det_1);

        switch (page) {
            case 1:
                header.setText(R.string.easy_mode);
                h1 = DEFAULT_INT;
                sh1 =  DEFAULT_INT;
                sd1.setText(String.valueOf(h1));
                break;

            case 2:
                header.setText(R.string.medium_mode);
                h1 = DEFAULT_INT + 1;
                sh1 =  DEFAULT_INT + 1;
                sd1.setText(String.valueOf(h1));
                break;

            default:
                header.setText(R.string.action_restart);
                h1 = DEFAULT_INT;        
                sh1 = DEFAULT_INT;          
                sd1.setText(String.valueOf(h1));
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setTextViewInfo(){
        sd1.setText(String.valueOf(h1));
    }
}
```

Or would it be better to send the information from my `activity` and load one or multiple `fragments` instead?

```
public class testActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 8;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testActivity);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.high_scores_pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new testActivity (getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    private class testActivityAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public testActivityAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    testFragment tf1 = new testFragment ();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return easy.newInstance(position);
                case 1:
                    testFragment2 tf2 = new testFragment ();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return medium.newInstance(position);

                default:
                    testFragment d = new testFragment ();
                    return d.newInstance();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

edit:

In my adapter, I just tried

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return HighScoresEasyFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 1:
        return HighScoresMediumFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 2:
        return HighScoresExpertFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 3:
        return HighScoresBrainFartFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 4:
        return HighScoresClassicFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 5:
        return HighScoresPuzzleFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 6:
        return HighScoresPerfectFragment.newInstance(position);
    case 7:
        return HighScoresPowerFragment.newInstance(position);
    default:
        return HighScoresEasyFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

ugh, but it didn't load anything...  my `constructor` is now...:

```
public static HighScoresEasyFragment newInstance(int pageNumber) {
    HighScoresEasyFragment fragment = new HighScoresEasyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

It loaded the first page's header but no data and it didn't load anything for second to 8th fragments...

Comment: I don't see a onCreateView method, are you inflating any layout? It seems to be you are fecthing textfields from the activity layout instead of the fragment layout. Is that the objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call notifyDataChanged() from your activity using your adapter reference. Basically notifyDataChanged just tells all your fragments in your adapter that data has changed and they should refresh themselves. Remove notifyDataChanged from your getItem() method and put it when you change data in your activity.

Comment: and i called notifyDataChange because the data didn't update and someone said add that method. I haven't a clue how it works, i've been trying to read up on it but I don't really understand view pager anymore since the tutorial on developer.android.com didn't give me the expected results. It just loaded a normal activity with a textview embedded in a scrollview.

Comment: ok. thanks for your assistance. I made some edits as well to my original post

Comment: I finally got it!  I ended up using FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.  It seemed to be much simpler to use.  Hopefully I won't have memory issues cause I believe that pageradapter doesn't destroy nonvisible pages.  Although I have 8 pages I'm hoping since there's only  textviews on theme it won't consume too much... :-/  Do you know best way to monitor and although fragments aren't destroyed it will once activity is destroyed right??

Comment: you can set your mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(100); to the number you want so pages not visible in that limit get destroyed, and they will for sure. And yes, an activity destroyed means all its children fragments